# R: Obtain Row Number of a Tibble Using dplyr Package

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I want to obtain the row number of any row that satisfies certain conditions.

In my `tibble` formation bellow, I want to obtain only the `row number` in which (p = 1, d = 1 q = 1)

```
tbl <- tibble::tibble(p = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2), d = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), q = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))

tbl
```

## A tibble: 10 x 3

|  | p | d | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

```
tbl |>  dplyr::filter(p == 1, d == 1, q == 1) |> 
  dplyr::row_number()

# p d q 
# 1 2 3
```

**What I Want**

I just want a function that will print the `row number` that has the desired quality such that I can make the function that produce it an object with a name the use it in another function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>%
  with(which(p == 1 & d == 1 & q == 1))
```

Output:

```
[1] 5
```

Which means it was the 5th row of your data.

Comment: New thing i learnt. Can you share how with() works? and great to see a base function fitting in dplyr.

Comment: @anuanand, `with` evaluates an expression in an environment constructed from your data. It is useful for simplifying calls to modeling functions.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `filter` with `across` or `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    filter(across(p:q, `==`, 1)) %>% 
    pull(rn)
[1] 5
```

---

Or using

```
tbl %>% 
  summarise(rn = which(if_all(p:q, `==`, 1)))
# A tibble: 1 × 1
     rn
  <int>
1     5
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rowSums` on a logical `matrix`

```
 which(rowSums(tbl == 1) == 3)
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

tbl %>% 
  rowid_to_column %>% 
  filter(p == 1 & d == 1 & q == 1) %>% 
  pull(rowid)

#> [1] 5
```